# Laravel is not sending Pusher Events to my Vue.js frontend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I have a Vue.js separated project from a Laravel backend in many tutorials I see a Laravel + Vue.js but I have a Vue.js SPA separated and I don`t know what I doing wrong.

I already make the configuration on front end, this is it:

```
 const pusher = new Pusher(configMain.PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
    cluster: configMain.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER
 });
 const pusherChannel = pusher.subscribe('teste');
 pusherChannel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

When I use the debug console in PUSHER and send an event, it works fine I receive it. But when I try to send an event from my backend Laravel project it doesn`t work.

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=********
PUSHER_APP_KEY=********
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=********
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=********
```

I already set the keys and change the driver, in config broadcasting i have this:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
    ],
],
```

I created an event in Laravel that is this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MyEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        //
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('teste');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }
}
```

And when i execute this in my backend:

```
event(new MyEvent('hello world'));
dd("ENTROU");
```

**My front doesn't receive it, I must do something that I don't see it?**

Comment: Try to log in to your event constructor. `Log::info('something');`

Comment: Are you able to see the events in the Pusher debug console? Have you created your channel on `routes/broadcast.php`?

Comment: I don't create my channek on broadcast, i need it?